# Removing a click EventListener to links that go to external sites

Tags: javascript, html, click, anchor, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add a vanilla page transition to my website.

The js (see below) I added is working with all my anchor but I want to know if there is a way to target link to external page that have `target="_blank"` or a class I can define so the function won't work for those links.

```
// PAGE TRANSITION
window.onload = () => {
  const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  const transition_el = document.querySelector('.transition');

  setTimeout(() => {
    transition_el.classList.remove('is-active');
  }, 350);

  for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    const anchor = anchors[i];

    anchor.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let target = getLink(e);

      console.log(transition_el);

      transition_el.classList.add('is-active');

      console.log(transition_el);

      setInterval(() => {
        window.location.href = target;
      }, 350);
    })
  }
}

function getLink(e) {
  if (e.target.hasAttribute("href"))
    return e.target.href;
  var parent = e.target.parentNode;
  while (parent != null && typeof parent.tagName != "undefined") {
    if (parent.hasAttribute("href"))
      return parent.href;
    parent = parent.parentNode;
  }
  return null;
}
```

For now, the event ignore my `target="_blank"`, does the transition and open the link in the same tab. Is there a way that I can check if the link is external and not do the transition?

PS. The function getLink(e) was just so that I wouldn't get undefined error for anchor with other stuff in it.

Comment: Use an `if` statement around `anchor.addEventListener()` that checks `anchor.getAttribute("target")`.

Comment: If you only want to do it for a specific class, change `querySelectorAll('a')` to `querySelectorAll('a.thatclass')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the not selector to exclude the targets

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a:not([target="_blank"])').forEach(a => a.classList.add('test'));
```

```css
a.test {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="//example.com">A</a>
<a href="//example.com">A</a>
<a href="//example.com" target="_blank">B</a>
<a href="//example.com" target="_blank">B</a>
<a href="//example.com">A</a>
```